# Spacelift - local run - is it possible

Tags: terraform, spacelift

I am trying to run my Spacelift stack with my files from a local folder, but using all the context / env vars etc that are present in my Spacelift stack, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could preview uncommitted local changes by using the local-preview subcommand of our API client, named [spacectl](https://github.com/spacelift-io/spacectl) :

```
spacectl stack local-preview --id <STACK ID>
```